# MySQL die if database or table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm importing a SQL script into phpMyAdmin using a MySQL database. I need to check if a database exists at the top of the script and return if it does not.

I know how to check if the database exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'MyDatabase')
```

But I don't know how to return when this value is zero. I've tried this:

```
IF NOT (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'MyDatabase')) THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END;
END IF;
```

This throws the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE ' at line 1
```

I also need to check if a table within that database exists and return if it does not. Again, I know how to check if the table exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'MyDatabase' AND table_name = 'MyTable')
```

But I don't know how to exit the script at this point.

## EDIT

I figured out that I can just put a `USE` statement at the top of the script, which will cause it to throw an error if the table doesn't exist:

```
USE `MyDatabase`;
```

This works well enough, but it would still be nice to know how to do this with a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with an if stament.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'
```

like:

```
 IF SCHEMA_NAME  = '' THEN
 --do this--
 ELSE
 -do this--
```